# How in-app purchase works in ios

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios7.1

I want to integrate payments in my ios app. I have no idea how in-app purchase works. Are we need to pay some amount for the apple for that? Can anybody give me a clear description about how inn-app purchase works in ios.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Too Have Just Started Reading Up On **"In-App Purchases"**
Here's A Link To Another Stack Question About **"In-App Purchases"** With Some Code

[How do you add multiple in-app purchases to an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027762/how-do-you-add-multiple-in-app-purchases-to-an-iphone-application)

**"Are we need to pay some amount for the apple for that?"**

**YES** You'll Need A Device Enabled Account To Test Your In-App Purchases On,
And **YES** They Receive A Percentage Of Each Transaction.

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

I Hope I've Shed Some Light On The Subject And Answered Your Question As Best I Can.