# How do you add multiple in-app purchases to an iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

okay, So i basically followed the tutorial in this link
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_In-App_Purchase_Tutorial
I also tried the tutorial in this one: [How do you add an in-app purchase to an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556336/how-do-you-add-a-in-app-purchase-to-an-iphone-application) but it did not work for me. I would really appreciate it if someone helps me out. I'm going to use the first link because that's the tutorial I used. It works fine for one in app purchase, BUT, how do i do it for more in app purchases? for more levels? The tutorial only teaches one, and so I try and follow the same tutorial but by changing the names, and it STILL doesn't work. The closest I got was it does purchase it, but it does not enable the button even though I connected the Outlets. Need help, the coding is provided below:

> ViewController.h

```
enter code here#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import "PurchaseViewController.h"
#import "SecondPurchaseViewController.h"

@interface MAGViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)purchaseItem:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *level2Button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) PurchaseViewController *purchaseController;

- (IBAction)SecondpurchaseItem:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *level3Button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondPurchaseViewController *SecondpurchaseController;


-(void)enableLevel2;
-(void)enableLevel3;
@end
```

And the .m file is: (i did put the #import "PurchaseViewController.h" so it's not that and i also put the Second one as well.

```
- (IBAction)purchaseItem:(id)sender {

_purchaseController.productID =
@"com.example.IAP.courseone";

[self.navigationController
 pushViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES];

[_purchaseController getProductInfo: self];
}

- (IBAction)SecondpurchaseItem:(id)sender {

    _SecondpurchaseController.SecondproductID =
    @"com.example.IAP.coursetwo";

    [self.navigationController
     pushViewController:_SecondpurchaseController animated:YES];

    [_SecondpurchaseController getSecondProductInfo: self];
}

-(void)enableLevel2
{
    _level2Button.enabled = YES;
}

-(void)enableLevel3
{
    _level3Button.enabled = YES;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _purchaseController = [[PurchaseViewController alloc]init];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
     addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];

    //

    _SecondpurchaseController = [[SecondPurchaseViewController alloc]init];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
     addTransactionObserver:_SecondpurchaseController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

PurchaseViewController.h is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface PurchaseViewController : UIViewController <SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *productDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;

- (void)getProductInfo:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

PurchaseViewController.m is:

```
@interface PurchaseViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MAGViewController *homeViewController;
@end


@implementation PurchaseViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

//// -->

-(void)getProductInfo: (MAGViewController *) viewController
{
    _homeViewController = viewController;

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                      [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    }
    else
        _productDescription.text =
        @"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings";
}

//
//

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}

////

- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

////

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

////

-(void)unlockFeature
{
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased"
                forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_homeViewController enableLevel2];
}

- (IBAction) restore{
    //this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %lul", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        if(SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            //called when the user successfully restores a purchase
            [self unlockFeature];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }

    }

}

//// <--



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;

}
```

How do i make it work for more than one IAP purchase? The ray wenderlick tutorial shows in a table view, but i don't want a table view, i want custom buttons with a custom background of my own, so this tutorial is great, but i don't know how to make it work with more than one iap. thank you in advance if u know the answer, please comment. i've been struggling over 2 days already.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial please refer this tutorial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .h file add this method.

```
 + (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance;
```

in implementaion file .m

```
+ (RageIAPHelper *)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static RageIAPHelper * sharedInstance;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
      NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                  @"com.razeware.inapprage.drummerrage",
                                  @"com.razeware.inapprage.itunesconnectrage",
                                  @"com.razeware.inapprage.nightlyrage",
                                  @"com.razeware.inapprage.studylikeaboss",
                                  @"com.razeware.inapprage.updogsadness",
                                  nil];
      sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
   });
  return sharedInstance;
}
```

by this we can get more productIdentifiers.

follow this tutorial [Click Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Hope this will help you.